# foreign key assignments using code first

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ef-code-first

I am creating a MVC application and want to generate the database using the Code First approach. I've done this with simple tables, but now that I am introducing Foreign Key relationships, things are getting muddled for me.

I have three classes, each of which will have their own table in the DataBase:

```
public class Device
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int InternalDeviceID { get; set; }

        public int DeviceID { get; set; }

        public string DeviceName { get; set; }

        public virtual EquipmentDevice EquipmentDevice { get; set; }
    }

public class Equipment
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int InternalEquipmentID { get; set; }

        public int EquipmentID { get; set; }

        public string EquipmentName { get; set; }

        public virtual EquipmentDevice EquipmentDevice { get; set; }
    }

public class EquipmentDevice
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int InternalEquipmentDeviceID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Equipment> EquipmentID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Device> DeviceID { get; set; }
    }
```

The relationship is that a Equipment may have many Devices, and a Device may belong to many Equipments (a many to many if I'm not mistaken). To organize which Equipments have what Devices associated with them, I am using the EquipmentDevice table, which will just pair their IDs together along with an internal ID for that table.

Based on other examples I have found, I had believed this to be the way in which to code such a situation, where the Many side of a relationship will have an ICollection<> object of the Single side, and the Single side of a relationship will have a virtual object of the Many side (both classes having a ICollection<> of the other for a N:N, or both having a virtual for 1:1)

However, when I create the database, my tables look like this:

**Device Table**[image]

**Equipment Table**
[image]

**EquipmentDevice Table**

[image]

Am I simply backwards in the way in which I am setting up foreign keys for my tables, or is there another problem I am missing altogether for this type of situation? I couldn't find an exceptionally helpful source of info on this subject. I'm also attaching what the diagram of these tables would look like as well, just to help be more clear.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close- the properties on Equipment and Device need to be ICollections.  You don't need to define a class for the join table, EF will take care of that for you.   Here's what your classes should look like (here's a good reference:)

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

```
    public class Device
            { 
                public Device() 
                { this.Equipments = new HashSet<Equipment>();}

                [Key]
                [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
                public int InternalDeviceID { get; set; }

                public int DeviceID { get; set; }

                public string DeviceName { get; set; }

                public virtual ICollection<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }
            }

    public class Equipment
        {

            public Equipment()
            { this.Devices = new HashSet<Device>(); }

            [Key]
            [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int InternalEquipmentID { get; set; }

            public int EquipmentID { get; set; }

            public string EquipmentName { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Devices> Devices { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Ah very nice - I wasn't aware EF would create the relational tables for you! Although, could you perhaps elaborate on the "public Equipment() ... HashSet" and "public Device() ... HashSet" part of the class? I don't think I've come across that in my examples so far

Comment: EF uses the HashSet objects to represent the collection properties on either side of the many-to-many relationship.  You have to "new" them up in the constructor so that they can be populated from the database or in memory, otherwise you get a NullReferenceException on DB load or when you try to work with one of the collections for a CRUD operation.

Comment: So let's say then that I have Table_A and Table_B. These have a 1:N relationship, respectively. I want to use the ID from Table_A as a FK in Table_B, but do not need any columns from Table_B to be present in Table_A. Since I am not creating a new table from this relationship, would Table_A just have a "public virtual Table_B objectname" property and Table_B have a "public virtual ICollection<Table_A> objectname" property, and that would carry the foreign key from A into B?

Comment: Yes that is true, but you should also use Fluent API to set the foreign key constraint on the 1 to many relationship because if you try to delete rows from Table A, you would get an error from EF if there are rows in Table B with foreign key values associated with rows in Table A

Comment: In looking at the table that was created with the help of this answer, I just realized I should have specified that the "Internal" IDs were not what I needed to make the EquipmentDevice table with, but rather the DeviceID and EquipmentID

Answer (score 1):

To generate foreign keys, the first thing to do is to create the models.

```
public class Device
{   
    [Key]
    public int DeviceID { get; set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }
}

public class Equipment
{        
    [Key]
    public int EquipmentID { get; set; }
    public string EquipmentName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

Then you generate and compile the driver for each of the models.
By generating the first model, creates the "Context".

[image]

After loading the project and check if you have access to the drivers created.

[image]

Now checks the database. The table has two foreign keys in the new table is automatically created.

Comment: What is the difference in using [Key] and [ForeignKey(string name)]?

Comment: Key is primary key. You assign a foreignkey cuando utilizas

Comment: "[Key]" is the primary key. The foreign key is assigned using the ICollection of Device and Equipment models.